# Increase Rcpp compile speed

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am using Rcpp to write an R package, which also uses some C++ code, but each time I do `R CMD build <package name>`, it needs a really long time to compile the whole packages, since there are couple of cpp files. Is there a way I can only compile the changed files/new files, instead of recompiling everything? Thank you very much!

I have a Makevars file like this:

```
PKG_CXXFLAGS=-std=gnu++11

PKG_LIBS=-L. -lall
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best trick I know is to deploy the **awesome** frontend [ccache](https://ccache.samba.org/) which most Linux distros have, and which OS X has too (in Brew IIRC). It can be used with both `g++` and `clang`.

So in `~/.R/Makevars` I have

```
VER=
CCACHE=ccache
CC=$(CCACHE) gcc$(VER)
CXX=$(CCACHE) g++$(VER)
SHLIB_CXXLD=g++$(VER)
FC=ccache gfortran$(VER)
#FC=gfortran
F77=$(CCACHE) gfortran$(VER)
```

where `VER` is currently empty as 4.9 is the default. Now if you re-build the same package over and over, the compile-time is very fast as unchanged code leads to object files being retrieved.